# Finding P(U <4) where U is uniformly distributed with known mean and variance

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution

I have been given a question:

```
if U is uniformly distributed with mean 5, and variance 3, what is P(U<4)?
```

This is all the information that has been given. I'm new to statistics and have tried to solve this using the formula:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}$

$\text{Mean} = \frac{a+b}{2}$

$\text{Var} = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$

and finding the $b-a$ by using the known variance. I've also tried using the moments method where:

$a= x̄ - s\sqrt3$

$b = x̄ + s\sqrt3$

In both cases i get the answer $1/6$ which sadly does not match the given answer of $1/3$.

Can someone explain how this is correctly calculated. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since $U$ has mean 5, it has support on $[5-\theta, 5 + \theta]$. Now use the known variance to compute $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/3 is the correct answer. Start by solving for $a$ and $b$ (the answer you have above doesn't look right), then find what fraction of the distance from $a$ to $b$ is below 4. Assuming $a < b$,  $P(U<4) = (4-a)/(b-a)$. Illustration below: the length of the blue line divided by the total length of the line from $a$ to $b$ is the probability $U  < 4$. [image]

Comment: I did get the correct answer with that formula but where does the formula : P(U<4)=(4−a)/(b−a) come from ?

Comment: What if P(U>4) would the formula remain the same ?

Comment: Try to reason it from the image. $b-a$ is the total 'distance' that probability is spread over. $(4-a)$ is the 'distance' that corresponds to $U < 4$.

Comment: so if it was P(U>4) would that mean P(U>4)=(b-4)/(b−a) ?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I actually understand how it works now:)

Comment: (4-a)/(b-a) in this case is the cumulative probability of a uniform random variable on [-5 , 5].

Comment: I am not sure where you get [-5,5]. Solving for a and b in the original post we have U as a uniform random variable over [2,8].